# TV series about a man who scammed his fiancée

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I recently watched a TV series where the plot revolves around a con man who scammed his fiancée to steal $3m. He then leaves her, convinced he's won. His fiancée then steals the money back, forcing him to retaliate. Unfortunately I can't remember the title.

Other things I can remember:

- Set in LA but has a lot of British actors/characters
- Fairly new as I remember seeing adverts for it about a year ago
- I think the main character is called Ben or Chris but I'm not entirely sure

I hope that's enough and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't seen the show myself, but I remember the ads for it.  This sounds a lot like [The Catch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catch_(TV_series)).

- Wife is a private investigator living in L.A.
- Started last year, so matches your timeline
- Her fiance is a con man who bilks her and runs away.  His name is Benjamin Jones.

[image]